# Test Run successfully, but Log's show java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I am not sure if it's IDE error, or something wring in my test method?
Any help would be appreciated.

> Log's :-

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at presenter.WeatherAppPresenter.getWeatherInfo(WeatherAppPresenter.java:36)
    at presenter.WeatherAppPresenterTest.getWeatherInfo(WeatherAppPresenterTest.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at util.RxSchedulersOverrideRule$3.evaluate(RxSchedulersOverrideRule.java:67)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
```

> Blockquote

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class WeatherAppPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    Wheatherappview wheatherappview;

    @Mock
    WeatherMapService weatherMapService;

    private WeatherAppPresenter weatherAppPresenter;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        weatherAppPresenter = new WeatherAppPresenter(wheatherappview, weatherMapService);
    }

    @Test
    public void getWeatherInfo()  {

        CityWeather cityWeather  = new CityWeather();
        String selectedcity = "selectedCity";
        String appId = "appId";
        Observable<CityWeather> cityWeatherObservable = Observable.just(cityWeather);

        when(weatherMapService.getWeatherByCityName(eq(selectedcity), 
        eq(appId))).thenReturn(cityWeatherObservable);

        //When
        weatherAppPresenter.getWeatherInfo(selectedcity);

        //Then
        verify(wheatherappview).showWeatherInfo(cityWeather);
    }
```

Comment: **1)** If you have a `try-catch` block in the method you're calling from the test, it might explain the log and the fact that your test is not stopped when the exception is thrown. **2)** Your test passes because you only verify that `wheatherappview).showWeatherInfo` while not checking the actual output of `weatherAppPresenter.getWeatherInfo`, which seems to be the method under test. Does it return something? What's it supposed to do?

Comment: weatherAppPresenter.getWeatherInfo is the method which call Retrofit API with Rx java, and in Sucees I am redirecting to the view methos. so I only verify the  the view method.  @Morfic